# Processing of visa from Govt website vs VFS Global

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, application-status

I am willing to travel to Canada on 11 November 2018. I submitted the application through the Government of Canada website (https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application.html) on 13 October 2018. There has been no update on the application up until now.

I saw and heard some people's experiences with VFS Global who said that they got their visa within 2 days of application.

Is there a difference in the processing of the two applications? From my understanding, VFS Global would also forward the request to Government of Canada for approval of someone's visit. I am a little confused. How long should I expect to wait?

I am from India and all my documents are pretty complete and genuine and have been submitted on the website alongwith the visa processing fee CAD 100.

Comment: You should [check your application status](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-status.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html the processing timescale for visitor visa applications from India is 44 days

Comment: I looked at that but I am curious how people got it within 2 days from VFS Global?

Comment: VFS Global in India? I’d imagine processing times depend on several factors including the number of applications received, the perceived country risk, what document verification checks checks may be required etc.